# Modelling a right-long-tailed distribution

Tags: probability, distributions

The plot below models a sample of departure delays of flights, the x-axis is minutes delayed. The mean is about 10 (red line) and std is 36. The distribution has a very long tail (some flights are 800 minute delayed). The blue line is a fitted normal (mean=10, std=36) and the purple distribution is a shifted Poison (such that it can handle negative values).

Both of them completely miss the data as the data has a long tail and is very skewed. How might I model the probability of flight delays best?

[image: skewed dataset]

Comment: I've also tried fitting a skewed normal, but it is also not fully capturing the dataset.

Comment: Your question will be better answered if you describe the reason for needing a parametric function.  (Not suggesting you don't have a reason.  It's just not given.)  Why not just fit a nonparametric density function?

Comment: You could perhaps consider a location-scale version of a non-central Student $t$-distribution which has 4 parameters (one more than the skew normal).  Yet another alternative is the variance-gamma distribution, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-gamma_distribution